# Android Beacon Library Advertising always on

Tags: android, service, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, foreground-service

I have a problem with the advertising mode of the Android Beacon Library. After a few hours the service responsible for advertising stops sending BLE Pakets.

I work in a project where the advertising service has to run all the time on a Smartwatch (Android Wear capable Smartwatch). It is important that the app is not visible to the user all the time, but can also be pushed into the background. If the responsible Android service is stopped for a short time, this is not so bad, but it should be restarted as soon as possible.

How can this be achieved? I've already read about a Foreground service for scanning, but it doesn't seem to exist for advertising.

I used this example code for a iBeacon Advertising service: https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/beacon-transmitter.html

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

On Android 8+ an app must be running in some form to remain advertising over BLE.  **The only way to keep an app running on Android 8+ is to create a foreground service.**

The Android Beacon Library provides [instructions on creating a foreground service](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/foreground-service.html) for the purpose of scanning for beacons.  As a side effect this same foreground service will also keep a transmitter going.

You may also just create your own [foreground service using Android APIs.](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)  The service doesn't even need to do anything -- it just needs to stay running to keep your transmitter from being shut off by the operating system.

Important note:  Some Chinese ROMs made by Huawei and OPPO have non-standard modifications will [kill foreground services unless the apps are whitelisted.](http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2019/04/30/the-rise-of-the-nasty-forks)